# ASP.Net/Jquery find client event after Response.End()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button that is generating a PDF file on the server and then setting the response header information to the client for the file to be downloaded.

I would like to display a "Please Wait..." message during the postback because it could be time intensive. I'm able to display a div with no problem when the button is clicked but I'm not able to hide this div when the server returns the information.

Below is my server side code:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Casefile.SerialCode + ".ppt");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(binaryData);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I've tried the following Jquery to hide my Div but it never gets called...

```
$(document).onLoad(function ()
{
   $('#divLoading').css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the exact same thing with this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#inProgress').hide();
        });
```

**EDIT**
You can try using the clientscriptmanager on your server side.

`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideDiv", "$('#inProgress').hide();", true)`

alternatively you can try something like:(in your javascript)

```
        Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

        function appl_init() {
            var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();               
            pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
        }

        function EndHandler() {           
            $('#inProgress').hide();
        }
```

Comment: This didn't work for the postback when I changed the response header (but it did on normal postbacks as expected). Any idea why it doesn't get called when using the C# code reference above?

Comment: I tried both of the options you added above, neither one gets called after my event. I even checked to see if the page contained the code from the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript and it was no where to be found.

Comment: Interesting, I use both of these methods as well.  It seems you are rewriting the response on a current page.  I usually have a seperate page specifically used for rewriting the response to some other file type.  I like doing this because it removes any other "oddities" that you may be doing on the page.  I will try to get you a sample written.

Comment: Also 1 more thing.  is your postback async or sync?  pgRegMgr.add_endRequest will only work on asyc, where pgRegMgr.add_pageLoaded will work on both async and sync.

Comment: I'm trying to move all of the logic to a separate page at the moment. At the moment, everything is a full postback (no callbacks). Just a regular asp.net button

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pageLoad = function()
{
    $('#divLoading').hide();
};
```

**EDIT:**
The reason why I went with pageLoad instead of $(document).ready is because pageLoad will fire on partial postbacks (UpdatePanels). From your code it looks like you're doing a full postback but the code should still work.

Comment: This didn't work for the postback when I changed the response header (but it did on normal postbacks as expected). Any idea why it doesn't get called when using the C# code reference above?